# How to group and aggregate different dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

`df1`

```
A B
a 1
a 1
a 4
b 1 
b 3
```

`df2`

```
A B
a 1
a 2
c 3 
c 5
```

`df1.groupby("A").size()`

```
a 3
b 2
```

`df2.groupby("A").size()`

```
a 2
c 2
```

I'd like to get following `size`aggregation

```
   df1 df2
a  3    2
b  2    0 
c  0    2
```

Are there any way to achieve this?
I'd like to know aggregation method.

If someone has opinion,please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: all you need to do is merge df1 and df2 to get that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use `pd.concat` on the two grouped dataframes and pass `axis=1` (This is essentailly an `outer` join with `pd.merge`, but the syntax is a bit more concise).
2. Then, just do some cleanup with `.fillna(0)`, rename columns as desired with `.rename()` and use `.astype(int)` to make the columns data types integers:

---

```
df3 = (pd.concat([df1.groupby("A").size(), df2.groupby("A").size()], axis=1)
      .fillna(0).rename({0 : 'df1', 1 : 'df2'}, axis=1).astype(int))
df3
Out[1]: 
   df1  df2
a    3    2
b    2    0
c    0    2
```

Comment: Can also do `df1.groupby("A").size().rename("df1")`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in pandas I would do an outer join.

```py
data = [['a','a','a','b','b'],[1,1,4,1,3]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df1.columns = ['A','B']

data = [['a','a','c','c'],[1,2,3,5]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df2.columns = ['A','B']

temp1 = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby("A").size())
temp2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.groupby("A").size())

df = temp1.merge(temp2,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)
df.fillna(0)
```

output

```
0_x 0_y
A       
a   3.0 2.0
b   2.0 0.0
c   0.0 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

In [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) is possible use parameter `keys` for new column names, because working with `Series`, then replace missing values and convert to integers:

```
df3 = (pd.concat([df1.groupby("A").size(), 
                  df2.groupby("A").size()], axis=1, keys=['df1','df2'])
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int))
print (df3)
   df1  df2
a    3    2
b    2    0
c    0    2
```

Another idea is first use `concat`, convert `MultiIndex` to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), so possible use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), last use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df3 = (pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['df1','df2'])
         .reset_index()
         .pivot_table(index='A', columns='level_0', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
         .rename_axis(columns=None, index=None)
       )
print (df3)
   df1  df2
a    3    2
b    2    0
c    0    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below:

```
In [883]: df1 = df1.groupby("A").size().reset_index()

In [884]: df2 = df2.groupby("A").size().reset_index()

In [886]: df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='outer').fillna(0).rename(columns={'0_x': 'df1', '0_y':'df2'}).set_index('A')
Out[886]: 
   df1  df2
A          
a  3.0  2.0
b  2.0  0.0
c  0.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #groupby using agg to rename axis.
   g=df1.groupby("A", as_index=False)['B'].agg({'df1':'size'})
    h=df2.groupby("A", as_index=False)['B'].agg({'df2':'size'})

#concat the resultant datframe, fffiil, bfill and dro duplicates

(pd.concat([g,h], ignore_index=True).sort_values(by='A').ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()



  A  df1  df2
0  a  3.0  2.0
1  b  2.0  2.0
3  c  2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a variant of @David's answer :

```
frames = {"df1": df1, "df2": df2}

pd.concat(
    {key: value.groupby("A").size() for key, value in frames.items()}, axis=1
).fillna(0)
```